# Bottom view in UIViewController flickering when push from UINavigationController

Tags: ios, xcode

I have three views in my view controller.

```
1 -> UIView (Header view)
2 -> UITableView
3 -> UIView (Bottom view)
```

this is how I add Autolayout constraints

http://postimg.org/image/k17t4hfb7/

Problem is it's views flickering when loading the view controller

http://postimg.org/image/ykuh5loh3/

is there anyway to avoid this ? any help will be appreciate

Comment: by the way I hide bottom bar when push.

Comment: when u push the view bottomview not display on bottom for sometime and after that it push to bottom right????

Comment: Exactly. I think UITableView height change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok....Done it...
check out the bottomview constraints:
`bottomspaceto:bottomlayout` 
it should be like this,
[image]